# Working With Temporary Tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have some link which show data on iframe with the help of temporary data from database
I am fetching this data with the help of query strings

The page with Links is

```
<style type="text/css">
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.Menu
{
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
.fr
{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    float:right
}

</style>
<div class="Menu">
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$sql="select * from NSEIndices_latest";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$tpnt=$row['TickerPlantCode'];  //nse indice code
$indexname=$row['IndexName']; //nse indice index name
?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://mastertrade.in/master/wpfiles/gtnsegainers.php?tpnt=<?php echo $tpnt;?>&indexname=<?php echo $indexname;?>" target="fr"><?php echo $indexname;?></a><br></td>
  </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
    <iframe height="780" width="780" scrolling="no" name="fr"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Now the link from above page fetch data with the help of query string at this page a temporary table is created by collectiong data from various tables
but am getting error while retrieve data from that temporary table

the page with temporary table is

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Company Name
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">High
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Low
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Last Price
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Prv Close
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Change
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">%Gain
      </th>
  </tr>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$tpnt=$_GET['tpnt'];
$indexname=$_GET['indexname'];
echo "1".$indexname. "<br>";
$query="SELECT nsepricequotes_latest.Symbol, nsepricequotes_latest.CompanyName, nsepricequotes_latest.HighPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.LowPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.LastTradedPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.ClosePrice, nsepricequotes_latest.NetChange, nsepricequotes_latest.PercentChange, nse_index_constituents.Tickerplant_index_code,nse_index_constituents.NSE_Index_Name
FROM nsepricequotes_latest, nse_index_constituents
WHERE nsepricequotes_latest.TickerPlantCode = nse_index_constituents.TickerPlant_scrip
AND PercentChange >0
ORDER BY PercentChange DESC ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "2".$indexname. "<br>";
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$Symbol1=$row1['Symbol'];
$CompanyName1=$row1['CompanyName'];
$HighPrice1=$row1['HighPrice'];
$LowPrice1=$row1['LowPrice'];
$LastTradedPrice1=$row1['LastTradedPrice'];
$ClosePrice1=$row1['ClosePrice'];
$NetChange1=$row1['NetChange'];
$PercentChange1=$row1['PercentChange'];
$Tickerplant_index_code1=$row1['Tockerplant_index_code1'];
$NSE_Index_Name1=$row1['NSE_Index_Name'];
}
echo "3".$indexname. "<br>";
$tbl="create TEMPORARY TABLE temppice(Symbol varchar(100),CompanyName varchar(200),HighPrice float(50),LowPrice float(50),LastTradedPrice float(50),ClosePrice float(50),NetChange float(50),PercentChange float(50),Tickerplant_index_code varchar(100),NSe_Index_Name varchar(100))";
$res=mysql_query($tbl);
if (!$res) { die('Temporary table creation failed: ' . mysql_error()); }
if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());
$intbl="Insert into temppice values('$Symbol1','$CompanyName1','$HighPrice1','$LowPrice1','$LastTradedPrice','$ClosePrice1','$NetChange1','$PercentChange1','$Tockerplant_index_code1','$NSE_Index_Name1')";
mysql_query($intbl);
if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());
echo "4".$indexname. "<br>";
$query1="Select * from temppice where NSE_Index_Name=$indexname";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
//if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
$symbol=$row['Symbol'];  
$CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
$HighPrice=$row['HighPrice'];
$LowPrice=$row['LowPrice'];
$previousclose=$row['LastTradedPrice'];
$ClosePrice=$row['ClosePrice'];
$netChange=$row['NetChange'];
$percentagechange=$row['PercentChange'];
?>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $CompanyName;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $HighPrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $LowPrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $previousclose; ?></td>
   <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $ClosePrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $netChange;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $percentagechange;?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

the error am getting is

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mastertr/public_html/master/wpfiles/gtnsegainers.php on line 58
```

Comment: Did you check if the same queries work using a MySQL client application?

Comment: yes they are working in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

`TEMPORARY` tables have lifetime of one connection, so if you create the table during one request from the browser, and then want to fetch data from it in another request.... it's no longer there. The table does not exist and your query fails with `no such table in database` error.

Comment: Don't use `TEMPORARY` table. Use ordinary table for caching. Also you might consider using some other caching mechanism.